# How do you clone remote repo and set up as a project in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-clone

I have tried to clone a remote github repository onto my computer and run it in Visual Studio. There is an option to clone a repository in Visual Studio, but all it does is clone it to a folder. I have the code, but it is not a project and I cannot build it. I know I would have to set up custom building configurations and that the project would not build right away, but how do I convert said folder into project in the first place?

I have tried using the cloning feature on Visual Studio, and it just creates a folder separate from my existing empty project. I  expected it to clone the code into the existing project I had. If it had done that I could configure build settings and run it.

Comment: A git clone operation never changes an existing folder, it always creates new ones, since a repo should be self-contained. How you build a certain repo is wholy dependent on that repo alone. So check the documentation for the project you want to build.

Comment: The project is my own and I simply wanted to use the git features in Visual Studio. The git repo does not have any build instructions, I just wanted to know how to set build configurations and run the code in Visual Studio.

Comment: ??? If it is your own project, how comes you don't know how to build it? You might need to rephrase your question to clarify your problem.

Comment: The project was previously compiled using Makefile in vscode. I liked all of the tools in Visual Studio, so I wanted to find a way to set up and build the code in Visual Studio, while also being able to push the project to github.

Comment: Got it. Then you first need to create a Visual Studio project. Just use the "new project" wizard in Visual Studio to create a new C++ project and then add the files there. You should find plenty of information on how to create and configure VS projects.